# drawstring bold and normal text

Tags: c#

have code:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
            {

                Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
                Font drawFontBold = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
                SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                g.DrawString("this is normal", drawFont, drawBrush, new RectangleF(350f, 250f, 647, 200));
                g.DrawString(" and this is bold text", drawFontBold, drawBrush, new RectangleF(350f, 250f, 647, 200));
            }
```

I need to get

> this is normal **and this is bold text**

But I receive overlay of second text on first

Comment: The rectangle specifies the positiom. Both texts have the same coordinates.

Comment: Change 647 and 200 in second DrawString regarding correct call of MeasureString method to concat it

Answer (score 5):

Try this code, might do the job.!!!

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
{
    Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
    Font drawFontBold = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    // find the width of single char using selected fonts
    float CharWidth = g.MeasureString("Y", drawFont).Width;

    // draw first part of string
    g.DrawString("this is normal", drawFont, drawBrush, new RectangleF(350f, 250f, 647, 200));

    // now get the total width of words drawn using above settings
    float widthFirst = ("this is normal").Length() * CharWidth;

    // the width of first part string to start of second part to avoid overlay
    g.DrawString(" and this is bold text", drawFontBold, drawBrush, new RectangleF(350f + widthFirst, 250f, 647, 200));
}
```

Comment: It's more helpful to explain your answer instead of just posting code.

Comment: added comments, was in bit rush last time. thanks for your point.

Comment: `float widthFirst = ("this is normal").Length() * CharWidth` — are you kidding?! "Arial" isn't a monospace font — and even with monospace fonts never do it in that way (there are diacritics «е»+« ̈»=«ё», Hangul «ᄒ»+«ᅡ»+«ᇶ»=«하ᇶ» and etc)! Just do `float widthFirst = g.MeasureString("this is normal", drawFont).Width`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use:

```
    float widthFirst = g.MeasureString("this is normal", drawFont).Width;
```