# How to draw normal and bold fonts and center align the full string

Tags: c#, system.drawing

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to draw few lines using C# (System.Drawing)  Graphics.DrawString method. Below is the code.

```
        _gr.DrawString("105 Not as pictured/described / 106 Faulty/damaged / 107 Order arrived late", fn, solidBlack, posX, posY += fn.GetHeight(), _alignCenter)
```

Here I need to have All the numeric values in Bold font, and also the whole statement should be center aligned.

I tried to split this to multiple _gr.Drawstring calls and concatenated using _gr.MeasureString to identify X position. (referred:  [drawstring bold and normal text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219696/drawstring-bold-and-normal-text/24220290) )
However, This will NOT center align the whole string.

Below is the sample of code I tried, which did not align the whole string center.

```
gr.DrawString("Return codes: ", fn, solidBlack, posX, posY, _alignCenter);

            _gr.DrawString("101 ", fnBold, solidBlack, posX += _gr.MeasureString("Return codes: ", fn).Width, posY, _alignCenter);

            _gr.DrawString("Style doesn’t suit me / ", fn, solidBlack, posX += _gr.MeasureString("101 ", fn).Width, posY, _alignCenter);

            _gr.DrawString("102 ", fnBold, solidBlack, posX += _gr.MeasureString("Style doesn’t suit me / ", fn).Width, posY, _alignCenter);
```

The expected output is as below, Bold numeric values and the full statement is center aligned. Any help is appriciated.
[image]

Comment: Calculate the total width, and then use (containerWidth-totalWidth)/2 as your starting point for drawing.

Comment: [ComboBox OwnerDrawVariable Font format size problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103375/7444103). See the `RenderText()` and `BuildDrawingString()` methods. Your `pattern` can be `\d+` or something more *subtle*, if needed.